# Azure API Management deployment using CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management

I am trying using [Azure DevOps Toolkit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit) for APIM CI/CD pipeline. I have followed the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDOXI2E6zYA) for setting it up. Looks like the setup shown in the video is quite outdated. It is difficult to find proper resources for setting up APIM CI/CD implementation. We cannot use dotnet-apim as customer wont encourage to use personally maintained source code.

We are not sure how they came up with a starter dev source repository from APIM. Whenever we extract the current APIM, we are not getting APIM master template.

Is it advisable to use this tool or approach for a production environment? If anybody setup this toolkit and ci/cd pipeline for apim, kindly help with some guidelines.

Comment: [CI/CD for API Management using Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/devops-api-development-templates) and [Build a CI/CD pipeline for API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/build-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-api-management/)

Comment: I have contacted Microsoft regarding this. They recommended using ApiOps(https://github.com/Azure/apiops) instead of azure DevOps toolkit

Comment: We've been using dotnet-apim with great results. Especially since you can parameterize any field.

Comment: @Levi I totally get it. But this is also forked from Azure DevOps toolkit ,right? Also our customer does not recommend repos maintained by individual developers. Also, We wanted to update some database entries while onboarding APIs, so that we can enable some approval workflow.